# Visual Studio Code does not recognize OpenSSL that is already installed [ibp-vscode-extension]

Tags: visual-studio-code, openssl, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I want to start using the IBM Blockchain Platform extension in Visual Studio Code 2017 using Windows 10.

After installing the extension, the prerequisites page informs that OpenSSL is not installed. However, I confirmed that OpenSSL is already installed in Windows.

I tried to find the answer to this problem online, but can't find it.
Is there a way to "allow" OpenSSL in Visual Studio Code? Or the problem is how I installed OpenSSL (through an .exe file)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this is how I resolved it! The info tab for OpenSSL explains where to install it!

Install to C:\OpenSSL-Win64

Comment: Isn't this the same guidance that @david_k offered back in February?

Comment: This solution worked for me. By default, the OpenSSL installer installs it in C:/ProgramFiles/OpenSSL-Win64. Reinstalling it at C:\OpenSSL-Win64 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The extension looks for openssl being in a very specific location, and it has to be installed to that location, ie
`OpenSSL-Win64`. Next it then tries to run `openssl.exe` in that folder to determine the correct version has been installed. So if any of these conditions aren't met then it will say that openssl is not installed.

If you still have problems and you think you have done everything correctly for openssl then you can skip the pre-requisite check and I suggest you raise a github issue about your setup at 
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues