# VS Code/IBM Blockchain requires OpenSSL 1.0.2 Version

Tags: openssl, ibm-blockchain

I am having problems to find a OpenSSL Version **1.0.2** for a download in windows.

I installed IBM Blockchain extension in VS Code and I was only able to find/download OpenSSL 1.1.1, but it is requiered only the Verison 1.0.2.

How can I get the windows version vor OpenSSL 1.0.2? Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was downloading openssl version 1.0.2 (e.g. `/openssl-1.0.2j-fips-x86_64/openssl-1.0.2j-fips-x86_64.zip`) from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/ . I just extracted the downloaded zip file and then renamed the folder from `OpenSSL` to `OpenSSL-Win64` and moved it to `C:\OpenSSL-Win64`. It has to be in that specific folder (for windows 64) from what I understand as said here: [Visual Studio Code does not recognize OpenSSL that is already installed [ibp-vscode-extension]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006763/visual-studio-code-does-not-recognize-openssl-that-is-already-installed-ibp-vsc)

Comment: Thank you @Nik Makar! Unfortunately it still didn t work.... But maybe the IBM BlockchainPlattform isnt the best choice for me..

Comment: What does it say in the ibm blockchain platform? Does it say that you have another version of openssl installed?
Are you sure that in the directory C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin is the correct version? E.g. can you go to a terminal and execute `cd C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin` and then execute `openssl version`. For me, it shows that I have `OpenSSL 1.0.2j-fips  26 Sep 2016`.
There are indeed other ways to run Smart Contracts.

Answer (score 1):

You can build from source, the README mentions which file contains the install instructions for each OS -  https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable

Alternatively you can find a binary (bearing in mind openSSL project doesn't distribute nor officially recommends any specific binary distribution) by clicking on the 'wiki' link here - https://www.openssl.org/community/binaries.html

Comment: Thank you @Iq179   My problem is, that am a beginner and I don´t have any clue how I can use the binary. I also tried the one on github, but honestly - I don´t get it :(  Do I just need to clone and run it? ..and then I have OpenSSL1.0.2 ?